# Carrying remote VLAN via 2 routers to the local gateway

Tags: vlan, cisco-ios, subnet, gns3

I have a serverA (192.168.15.1) from site A and VLAN is 15, however the VLAN 15 gateway is set at site B (192.168.15.254).

There are two ISP routers as a metro role to connect each other by subnet 10.0.0.0/30.

My question is how can I get past those two routers? Could any one give an example to accomplish this? Thanks.

[image: scenario]

PS. I can ping from serverA (192.168.15.1) to an interface f0/0@R1(10.0.0.1), no more further.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: no, this question probably would appear on my incoming company migration

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information. For example, what are the network device models and configurations? You can refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance, then edit your question to include the necessary information. Speculation and guessing are off-topic here, as are questions about network not under your direct control

Comment: Do both 192.168.15.1 and 192.168.15.254 use the same /24 subnet? Can you configure the routes on R1 and R2? Is it possible to split 192.168.15.0/24 into 192.168.15.0/25 and 192.168.15.128/25 ?

Comment: @Zac67 i did it, it seems fine, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can use **Ether in IP**, defined in [RFC 3398](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3378) to tunnel ethernet through IP, if you equipment supports it.  It's similar to the VxLAN approach, but a little simpler and older.
- If you don't have those and it's desperate, you could think about **proxy ARP**.  It is really not recommended.

Do you have a particular reason to bridge like this?

I'd suggest you strongly consider **renumbering** so you can just use ordinary IP routes.  Perhaps you are nearly there already, if 192.168.15.0/25 is left and 192.168.15.128/25 is right?  Renumbering R1 f0/1 (.126?), change masks, add routes to R1 and R2.

Comment: the servers temporarily stay at site A due to relocation schedule problem, the new core switch will be set up at site B.

Comment: ive tried to add a static route and split them into /25, it works

Answer (score 3):

You can use VxLAN, defined in [RFC7348](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7348), to span a VLAN onto different sites.

Basically it encapsulates a VLAN into IP.

This off course add some overhead, and your routers at each endpoint need to support VxLAN